# Windows 7 cannot install some updates

Tags: windows-7, updates

i did all the proposed updates from WSUS but there are some of them that i can't install.
Most of the available updates are "Security update pack" like 2019-11 2019-09 and so on.
If i try to install them but i get an error, i've tried: clean disk with microsoft disk cleaner, clean the catalog but nothing worked for me.

What can i do to have a green page when i try to check for updates?
Thank you.

Comment: Windows 7 has reached EOL. One should not use it anymore. Using the official MS upgrade tool, one can still upgrade to Windows 10 for free.

Comment: And license still remains genuine? It's really important to have a original license here.

Comment: Try WSUS Offline to see if that will bring you up to date. I have a Windows 7 virtual machine that I have kept current and updates sill work on this machine (although there are any now) http://download.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: You might need the latest servicing stack update KB4562030 (64bit W7) or KB4565354 (32bit) , go to this page and search for the one that applies to you, download and install it>>>>>>>https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx

Comment: after installation of that try the updates again.

Comment: Cannot install the windows6.1-kb4562030-x64.

Comment: I tried to install KB4562030 but system logs says: Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80092004: Security Update for Windows (KB4562030).